# How to disable "Leave site" Button for a non admin user in alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am currently working on the alfresco community edition 5.2.

Now i am working on customizing the header option for non admin user. Now i am trying to disable leave site button for the non admin user in alfresco.

So can anyone give me solution for this problem.

Thanks and regards,
Amar.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to hide rather disabling the menu action.
You have to extend, share-header.get.js and you can use the below code.

```
if (!user.isAdmin) {
  widgetUtils.deleteObjectFromArray(model.jsonModel, "id", "HEADER_LEAVE_SITE");
}
```

You can refer the below link also.
https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-forum/disable-button-quot-leave-site-quot-from-the-header-on-alfresco/m-p/79956

HTH

Comment: Thank you sir for your reply. I have tried this code it removes that option. Now i want to remove that icon from the site also.Can you help me with this please.

Comment: It should be removed from the site also. If not, please let me know.

Comment: Hello sir,

i have tried this but it did not remove that icon from the site. Can you please help me with this.


regards,
Amar.

Comment: Please let me know, if you're facing this issue